# Wi-fi adapter not found error with Lenovo IdeaPad S540 14IML and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi, ideapad

I recently purchased a Lenovo IdeaPad S540-14IML, with wireless card "Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz". I've installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS, and though the WiFi works fine on Windows 10, I get the classic "No WiFi Adapter Found" message when looking in WiFi settings. I've tried out a number of possible solutions found in different threads, to no avail, so I've re-installed Ubuntu and hope any of you kind folk can lend me a hand.

Some of what I've tried so far:

-turning off Windows Fast Startup

-replacing the relevant umod file in /lib/firmware/ with the most up to date firmware for the Intel 9560, both from Intel's website (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) and failing that, from git (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/stats/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode), then entering "modprobe iwlwifi"

-it's not a RealTek wireless card as mentioned, but I tried installing the drivers from https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce anyway, though I've since reinstalled Ubuntu so that this failed attempt didn't mess with anything

-checked for blocks in the rfkill list (there are none)

-fully updated Ubuntu 18.04

-It's not a global connectivity issue because I'm able to use internet on my laptop from my phone via bluetooth

Here's some output that may be helpful:

```
sudo lshw -c network

  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:b1318000-b131bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: 0c:7a:15:16:3a:9f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.64 multicast=yes
```

```
lspci -nnk

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

bnep0     no wireless extensions.
```

```
rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
dmesg | grep iwlwifi

[    2.429958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    2.429961] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.429962] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.430167] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.13675109.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.452946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x354
[    2.459913] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.460338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.487742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    3.487816] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.487818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 2078277280
[    3.487819] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.13675109.0
[    3.487821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4D7BDBBB | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    3.487821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC5BC0048 | trm_hw_status0
[    3.487822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9BEDC70E | trm_hw_status1
[    3.487823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7761CB02 | branchlink2
[    3.487824] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x73E65F6B | interruptlink1
[    3.487824] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x81882239 | interruptlink2
[    3.487825] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x09B2CD8C | data1
[    3.487826] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBCE26AEF | data2
[    3.487827] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5567DAD | data3
[    3.487827] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x89D40C00 | beacon time
[    3.487828] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31868332 | tsf low
[    3.487829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF2463A4D | tsf hi
[    3.487830] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEB598D6D | time gp1
[    3.487831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0A023D38 | time gp2
[    3.487831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDCFED0EA | uCode revision type
[    3.487832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC1C4F95D | uCode version major
[    3.487833] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8BAB7EEB | uCode version minor
[    3.487834] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x018C3340 | hw version
[    3.487834] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5262E743 | board version
[    3.487835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x694A2202 | hcmd
[    3.487836] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB3C347DA | isr0
[    3.487837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9E3DBCB8 | isr1
[    3.487837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x19047D60 | isr2
[    3.487838] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x64A8A33E | isr3
[    3.487839] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEE82AEE | isr4
[    3.487840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5FCEB3BE | last cmd Id
[    3.487840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x068F20E5 | wait_event
[    3.487841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20EC4428 | l2p_control
[    3.487842] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAE8E1FE9 | l2p_duration
[    3.487843] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAC72CEB3 | l2p_mhvalid
[    3.487843] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB1521E3F | l2p_addr_match
[    3.487844] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5E434641 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    3.487845] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7BFDBF5E | timestamp
[    3.487846] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x85B94E75 | flow_handler
[    3.487878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.487879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    3.487880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    3.487881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    3.487881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
[    3.487882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    3.487883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    3.487884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[    3.487884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
[    3.487885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3
[    3.487886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    3.487887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x13675109 | umac minor
[    3.487887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005CB7 | frame pointer
[    3.487888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[    3.487889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    3.487890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    3.487906] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    3.487908] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    3.487910] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    3.487912] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    3.487915] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    3.487917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x46065A00 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    3.487919] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    3.487922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    3.487924] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    3.487926] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.487931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.487935] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    3.487969] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    3.487998] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c26, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    3.487998] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.488001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    3.499790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Thanks for any help you can give, I've been using Ubuntu for over a decade now and I'd really rather avoid going back to Windows :S

**EDIT**

Chili555's solution works perfectly, please see other thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may have had the same issue with Ubuntu 19.10 on an L13 Yoga thinkpad. The issue was resolved by reverting to an older kernel, in my case 5.3.0-18 works, but anything later than that does not.

If you just installed recently you may have gotten the new 18.04.4 point release which comes with the new 5.3 Kernel and could have the same exact issue.

run

uname -a

it should tell you which kernel you have, if it's newer than 5.3.0-18 you probably have the same issue as me.

You can install 5.3.0-18 using apt or the synaptic package manager.

Comment: Hey Sergiy, looks like it's 5.3.0-42, I'll work on downgrading to 5.3.0-18 and let you know. Thanks!